# Entering Webook in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-automation

I have a runbook that is triggered using a Webhook. All works well when I call this runbook via JavaScript or PowerShell. Would like to be able to also interactively trigger using the portal. Tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) but to no avail, entered the Webhook in any format I could think of, including what is listed on above page.

The input in the Automation Runbook job is always different from what it is when triggering not via portal. For example entering in the portal:

`{"WebhookName":"mywebhook","RequestBody":"[\r\n {\r\n \"ResourceGroup\": \"weu-co-rsg-automation-01\",\r\n \"Name\": \"w0001\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"ResourceGroup\": \"vm02\",\r\n \"Name\": \"vm02\"\r\n }\r\n]"}`

will result in:

`"{\"WebhookName\":\"mywebhook\",\"RequestBody\":\"[\\r\\n {\\r\\n \\\"ResourceGroup\\\": \\\"weu-co-rsg-automation-01\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Name\\\": \\\"w0001\\\"\\r\\n },\\r\\n {\\r\\n \\\"ResourceGroup\\\": \\\"vm02\\\",\\r\\n \\\"Name\\\": \\\"vm02\\\"\\r\\n }\\r\\n]\"}"`

Below is a screenshot of what is displayed in the Azure Automation portal:

[image]

Comment: Not very clear about your question. Do you put the {"WebhookName":"mywebhook",xxx} in the Test pane -> parameters? then output it to console, it changes to "{\"WebhookName\":\"mywebhook\",xxx}". Am I right?

Comment: No need to do an output to console, just listing the input parameters in the Azure Automation portal (see screenshot I added above).

Comment: Hi Felix, since this is by design, could you please accept it as an answer? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, and does not affect the function of runbook.

In the screenshot you attached, the input parameters are escaped, so it's different with what your original input.

You can also use this [online tool](http://easyonlineconverter.com/converters/dot-net-string-escape.html) to check the original input and escaped input.

[image]

Comment: Afraid this is not working. I'm simply trying to get the example on this page working:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks

No matter what I try, I can't get it working when entering the Webhook manually in the UI. Not when entering what is listed in the documentation nor when using what you outline above. BTW this is an issue of Azure Automation, not escaping.